# Autocommit on row exit in MudTable

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I am new to MudBlazor and I am playing around with the MudTable example that's provided and I was wondering if there is a way to autocommit records without using the commit button?

the example for reference:

```
<MudTable Items="@Elements" Dense="@dense" Hover="@hover" ReadOnly="@ronly" CanCancelEdit="@canCancelEdit" Filter="new Func<Element,bool>(FilterFunc)"
          @bind-SelectedItem="selectedItem1" SortLabel="Sort By" CommitEditTooltip="Commit Edit"
          OnCommitEditClick="@(() => Snackbar.Add("Commit Edit Handler Invoked"))" RowEditPreview="BackupItem" RowEditCancel="ResetItemToOriginalValues"
          RowEditCommit="ItemHasBeenCommitted" IsEditRowSwitchingBlocked="@blockSwitch" ApplyButtonPosition="@applyButtonPosition">
    <ToolBarContent>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Periodic Elements</MudText>
        <MudSpacer />
    </ToolBarContent>
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<Element, object>(x=>x.Number)">Nr</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<Element, object>(x=>x.Sign)">Sign</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Nr">@context.Number</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Sign">@context.Sign</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
    <RowEditingTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Nr">@context.Number</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Sign">
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="@context.Sign" Required />
        </MudTd>
        </MudTd>
    </RowEditingTemplate>
    <PagerContent>
        <MudTablePager />
    </PagerContent>
</MudTable>


<MudSwitch @bind-Checked="@canCancelEdit" Color="Color.Info">Can Cancel Edit</MudSwitch>


@code {
    private List<string> editEvents = new();
    private bool hover = true;
    private bool canCancelEdit = false;
    private bool blockSwitch = false;
    private Element elementBeforeEdit;
    private IEnumerable<Element> Elements = new List<Element>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Elements = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Element>>("webapi/periodictable");
    }

    private void ClearEventLog()
    {
        editEvents.Clear();
    }

    private void AddEditionEvent(string message)
    {
        editEvents.Add(message);
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private void BackupItem(object element)
    {
        elementBeforeEdit = new()
        {
            Sign = ((Element)element).Sign,
            Name = ((Element)element).Name,
        };
        AddEditionEvent($"RowEditPreview event: made a backup of Element {((Element)element).Name}");
    }

    private void ItemHasBeenCommitted(object element)
    {
        AddEditionEvent($"RowEditCommit event: Changes to Element {((Element)element).Name} committed");
    }

    private void ResetItemToOriginalValues(object element)
    {
        ((Element)element).Sign = elementBeforeEdit.Sign;
        ((Element)element).Name = elementBeforeEdit.Name;
        AddEditionEvent($"RowEditCancel event: Editing of Element {((Element)element).Name} cancelled");
    }

}
```

I don't know any method of really solving this so I am sorry if this post is asked wrong.
It seems time consuming to commit each record and I was hoping someone has a better way of thinking to go about committing without hitting a button

Comment: There is a [feature request](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/3659) for this. Currently I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RowEditPreview to store your data.
The changes to the previous row are committed in that case.
Not ideal but works for my requirement.